# for loop with multiline data

Tags: bash, for

I need to create a script with a loop through a list of items. I want to insert a string in the script.

I tried:

```
for i in "
a
b
c";
do
 echo "test "$i
done
```

But that only outputs one string:

```
test a b c
```

How would I get this?

```
testa
testb
testc
```

(`a`, `b` and `c` are just examples for some longer words, which I got from an OpenOffice Calc file)

Comment: Where are you getting the `abc` list from?  A file?  Typing it directly?  Standard input?

Comment: i want to create a script and have this in the clipboard

Comment: And how do you plan to access this "clipboard" from the script?  Pasting into standard input?  Using something like `xclip`?

Comment: I understand your question. you want me to improve the question itself... i edited it now

Comment: Why noone mentioned tr " " "\n"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
export a="
a
b
c
"

for i in $a; do echo "test$i";done
```

Comment: I just wonder, what's the difference to my script? why do you need to put the string in a variable $a first?

Comment: this solves it too: `for i in $(echo "a b c"); do echo "test$i";done`

Comment: @rubo77 The difference is the `$a` is unquoted, meaning that it undergoes word splitting, whereas `"a b c"` is quoted, so the shell sees it as all one word.

Comment: Note that it undergoes _work splitting_ **and** _filename generation_. Also, the "export" doesn't make sense here. What's wrong with `for i in a b c; do echo "test$i"; done`?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas you're right, export is not needed within the script-

Comment: Sure it is needed, cause i asked for a big input list that I want to split. A b c was just an example, the real data is much bigger and contains linebreakes as separations

Comment: If the string lines have spaces in between the characters, the for loop may not work as you desire.

Comment: +1 @cgseller it seems the loop goes over the white-space-delimited text, not newline. It is similar to what you see in `echo $a` vs `echo "$a"`. But `for i in "$a" ...` also does not work.

Answer (score 25):

You'd use a `while` loop instead.

```
while read i
do
  echo "test$i"
done <<< 'a
b
c'
```

Comment: For the curious, this is called a "here string", which is a variant of "here documents", which use two less-than signs and a delimiter at the end and beginning of the content